# The dimension of a continuous function... How to find that?

Tags: linear-algebra

How to find the dimension of a function? I just get confused of that:

Consider the set of continuous functions on the interval $[0,1]$:
$$C[0,1]=\{f:[0,1]\mapsto \mathbb{R} | f\text{ is continuous}\}$$
Then, what is the dimension of $C[0,1]$?

How can I find the dimension of $C[0,1]$ and how can I verify that?

Comment: It's not "a function" that has a dimension, it's a vector space of functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$C[0,1]$ is an infinite-dimensional space.  For example, $1, x, x^2, x^3 , \ldots$ are linearly independent.

Comment: From my intuition, it should be infinite. But how can I verify and prove that? Just give an example? I do not think that is enough.

Comment: You can check by defition: take $\lambda _1 ,\lambda _2, \cdots ,\lambda _n$ such that $\lambda _1 x^{k_1}+\lambda _2 x^{k_2}+\cdots+\lambda _n x^{k_n}=0 \forall x\in [0,1]$ A polynomial with infitite zeros is the trivial so you are done

Comment: Also a vector space has infinite dimension if it has a set of vectors such that every finite subset of them is linearly independent

Comment: A set of vectors is linearly independent if every finite subset of that set is linearly independent.  That is, by definition if
a set is linearly dependent it has a nontrivial linear combination that is $0$, and a linear combination involves only a finite collection of vectors.

Comment: Which kind of infinite? @RobertIsrael

Comment: The cardinality of a basis of $C[0,1]$, as with any separable infinite-dimensional Banach space, is $\mathfrak c$ (the cardinality of the continuum).  See e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141535/cardinality-of-a-hamel-basis-of-ell-1-mathbbr).