# Prove $\dim X = \mathfrak{c}$ for every infinite dimentional Banach space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

> Let $X$ be an infinite-dimensional Separable Banach Space. Prove that $\dim X=\mathfrak{c}$.

On the direction of $\dim X\ge \mathfrak{c}$, I thought taking the subset of all elements $x\in X$ which can be represented as an convergent expansion $$X\ni x = \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_ne_n$$ where $$e_n^i=\cases{0\quad i\neq n \\1\quad i=n,}$$ which will be mapped to $\ell^\infty$, a space of cardinality $\mathfrak c$ by the isomorphism $x\mapsto(c_1,c_2,\dots)$.

About the other direction I don't have any clue. We know that a Banach space with a basis must be separable but how can we use that fact to find out that $\dim X\le\mathfrak{c}$?

Comment: What is $\aleph$? If you mean $|\mathbb R|$, please use $\mathfrak c$ instead.

Comment: To show that $\dim X\le 2^{\aleph_0}$, show that $|X|=2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: That was exactly what I meant. changed it.

Comment: @JonasMeyer but that's exactly what I need to prove (that $|X|=2^{\aleph_0}$). so as I said I can't prove only the $\le$ direction.

Comment: To make sure we're talking about the same thing: By $|X|$ I mean cardinality, not dimension (that is why I wrote something different from $\dim$).  It is assumed that $X$ is separable.  You can show that every separable metric space has cardinality at most $2^{\aleph_0}$.  The other direction is harder; I don't understand what you've written, but you can find a solution at http://math.stackexchange.com/q/141535/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $Q$ be a countable dense subset of your Banach space $X$. In particular, every element of $X$ may b written as the limit of a sequence of points in $Q$, so there is an onto map $Q^{\mathbb{N}} \to X$, hence $$|X| \leq |Q^{\mathbb{N}}| = \mathfrak{c}.$$ On the other hand, $$|X| = |\mathbb{K}| \cdot \dim (X)$$ where $\mathbb{K}= \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ is your field. Therefore, $$\mathfrak{c} \geq |X|= \max( \mathfrak{c}, \dim(X))$$ hence $\dim(X) \leq \mathfrak{c}$.

Comment: but isn't your proof assumes that $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ or in general $\dim\mathbb{K}=\mathfrak{c}$?

Comment: Yes. Do you work is an arbitrary field? In that case, you should precise your definition of normed vector space: the field has to be at least valued.

Comment: What do you mean by "valued"? e.g I can also talk about $\mathbb{H}^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: I mean that the field has to have an absolute value. See for example http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Valuation.html. What does $\mathbb{H}^{\aleph_0}$ denote?

Comment: Banach spaces which are neither real nor complex are *silly*.