# Is it true that $c_0$ is isomorphic to $l^1$ as a vector space?

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

> Let $c_0$ be the vector space of complex sequences converging to $0,$ taken with the sup-norm.
>
> Is it true that $c_0$ is isomorphic to $l^1$ as a vector space?

Update: Is it also true that $c_0$ is isomorphic to its dual space as a vector space?

Comment: $\ell_1$ is the dual of $c_0$, so I don't understand your update.

Comment: Isomorphic as *what*? And what *type of dual*?

Comment: I wonder both algebraic and continuous

Comment: @ErginSuer, no infinite-dimensional vector space is vector-space isomorphic to its algebraic dual...

Comment: Is my answer satisfactory? If not, please let me know and I will elaborate more.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, because they have cardinality continuum and, being infinite-dimensional Banach spaces, [they have Hamel bases of cardinality at least continuum](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/141543/17929) hence of cardinality exactly continuum. Two vector spaces over the same field are isomorphic if and only if they have bases of the same cardinality.

Arguing in the same way, we conclude that even $c_0$ and $\ell_\infty$ are isomorphic as vector spaces.