# Dimension: Hilbert vs. Hamel

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, hamel-basis

Given two Hilbert spaces.

Clearly, equal Hilbert dimension implies equal Hamel dimension.
(Similarly, equal Hamel dimension implies equal cardinality.)

But what about the converse?
(Sadly, I couldn't find something on MSE.)

Comment: I think the first answer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141535/cardinality-of-a-hamel-basis-of-ell-1-mathbbr has the answer, if I am interpreting correctly.