# Proof that Separable Banach Spaces are Homeomorphic and Continuum Hypothesis

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, cardinals

I was trying to prove the claim that separable infinite dimensional Banach spaces are all homeomorphic, but I fell into a trap that relies on the Continuum Hypothesis.

My reasoning was as follows:

Call the space $X$. By Baire $X$ has dimension $D > \aleph_0$.

The number of points we can get to via sequences of the countable dense subset is at most $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}$ = $|\mathbb{R}|$.

There are $|\mathbb{R}|$ points in each dimension of $X$.

Each point is a countable sum of points on at most $\aleph_0$ dimensions.

So there are at most $|\mathbb{R}| D^{\aleph_0}$ points in $X$.

So $|\mathbb{R}| \geq |\mathbb{R}| D^{\aleph_0} = |\mathbb{R}| D$ points in $X$.

So we have $D \leq |\mathbb{R}|$.

But now I don't know if there's a way to fix this argument to show that $D = |\mathbb{R}|$ without assuming CH. I also would like to avoid using the high powered theorems typically needed for this proof.

Comment: Have you seen https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141535/cardinality-of-a-hamel-basis-of-ell-1-mathbbr and the cited one-page proof by Lacey?

Comment: Sorry, I'm really tired and what I said was bogus. I deleted my comment, the answer you cited answered my question, thanks.

Comment: Ok, glad to hear it :-)

Comment: Thank you for answering. I want to upvote or select this as the answer so I can close my question.

Comment: I posted it as an answer so you may do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Cardinality of a Hamel basis of $\ell_1(\mathbb{R})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141535/cardinality-of-a-hamel-basis-of-ell-1-mathbbr).  The answer by t.b. cites a half-page paper that gives an elementary proof of the desired result:

> H. Elton Lacey, *[The Hamel Dimension of any Infinite Dimensional Separable Banach Space is $c$](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2318458),* Amer. Math. Mon. **80** (1973), 298.