# dimension of an infinite-dimensional Banach space is $\geq c $.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

Here $c$ means the cardinal number of the continuum.

This is an exercise (4.8.7) in the book of Avner Friedman, 'foundations of modern analysis'.

I am a little bit surprised.

Just consider the $l^2$ Hilbert space. It is well-known that it has a basis $\{e_n = (0,0,\ldots, 1, 0,\ldots )\}$, which is countable. As I understand, $l^2$ is a Banach space, a Hilbert space actually, whose dimension is countably infinite.

In which place am I wrong?

Comment: The basis which you mention of $l^2$ is not a basis in the same sense of the exercise you refer. In the exercise, the author probably means the dimension in the purely algebraic sense. That basis of $l^2$ is not a basis in this sense, it is a basis in the sense that the closure of its span is $l^2$. It seems that the answers in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/141535) address the problem you want.

Comment: Isn't $\{e_i\} $ a Schauder basis? IIRC, there's a theorem which says that a Banach space cannot have a **Hamel** basis of countable cardinality.